# What number of citations would be impressive for an undergraduate?

Tags: citations, research-undergraduate

Currently applying for a research-related job in my field while in the last year of my undergraduate degree. I have conducted research and have publications in this field. I am wondering if the number of citations I have for my work is relevant, and if so, how many would I need to gain benefit by mentioning it? (I have 50)

The broad field is Computer Science.

Comment: Non-academic job search is probably off topic here. But few undergraduates have any publications or citations.

Comment: Agree with Buffy: any number of publications greater than zero is good for an undergraduate. Beyond that, I don't think it matters hugely (unless one of them is in Nature / Science).

Comment: One --- one citation is impressive for an undergraduate.

Comment: Non-academic job search is probably off topic here. But few undergraduates have any publications or citations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**One** --- one citation is impressive for an undergraduate.

Answer (score 3):

> Currently applying for a research-related job in my field while in the last year of my undergraduate degree.

In general, if you are an undergraduate then citations won't matter. It depends on the place and the position you're applying for. Again, another factor remains, i.e., the number of people applying for that same job position. In this situation, the organization that posted for the job vacancy would have to make a decision to choose the *right candidate* for their vacancy. Now, the word `'right candidate'` is relative in nature.

When a huge number of candidates apply for a single job position then one of the ways the recruiters tend to choose is to find ways to reject a candidate. If this happens then a higher number of publications(*and/or citations*) would give you a better edge. But it's all relative to the situation you are in. The choosing criteria can be absurd sometimes, but having a good research publication and citation at your level would always provide you with an extra edge.

You also have to `look into the job requirements carefully` to find out how much your research and publications are related to the specific requirements of the research-related job you mentioned.

So, No, there is no proper rule for undergraduates to have citations until you stand out in their eyes in some way or the other. That can be your research, your attitude towards the job, your direct relation(*your previous research and publications*) to the job criteria or sometimes even a good recommendation. A large number of factors can contribute to your success in getting the job.